# chart.js v2 update chart without global variable

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js2

I am using chart.js v2.5.0.

I want to create charts dynamically without using a global variable.

For example, I want to use code similar to this:
https://jsfiddle.net/DUKEiLL/sf57xw6b/

```
        function UpdateChart(ctrl) {
        var config = $("#" + ctrl).data("ChartJs");
            config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function () {
                    return randomScalingFactor();
                });
            });

            var ctx = document.getElementById(ctrl).getContext("2d");
            var TempMyDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
            TempMyDoughnut.update();
    }
```

But it doesn't work properly: when the user presses "update" button and hovers over the chart, previous instance are suddenly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating a new chart on each execution of `UpdateChart` function, hence you would have to destroy any previous instance of chart to prevent the hover issue.

To accomplish so, you could simply replace your `UpdateChart` function with the following ...

```
function UpdateChart(ctrl) {
    var config = $("#" + ctrl).data("ChartJs");
    config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
            return randomScalingFactor();
        });
    });

    // destroy previous instance of chart
    var meta = config.data.datasets[0]._meta;
    for (let i in meta) {
        if (meta[i].controller) meta[i].controller.chart.destroy();
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById(ctrl).getContext("2d");
    var TempMyDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

Here is the **[working example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6rzatzh/)**